# What is the proper way to open an Elementor modal within the editor?

Tags: javascript, php, elementor

I am trying to write an elementor extension that adds functionality to Elementor Forms via a custom action. The action shows, and I have setup a Field Mapping Control Box, that has a button within it called "Field Mappings".

When its clicked, I have it trigger a JS event, that shows the click, but I cannot seem to get a modal to open up? The goal is to open a modal that lists the Elementor forms fields in one column, and then shows a list of drop downs of fields from the remote system (its a CRM) allowing the configuration of a relationship between the Elementor Form fields and the CRM's fields.

Here is what I have so far:

1. Our control registration.

```
            'field_mapper',
            [
                #'label' => esc_html__( 'Map Fields', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::BUTTON,
                'separator' => 'before',
                'button_type' => 'success',
                'text' => esc_html__( 'Map Fields', 'textdomain' ),
                'event' => 'namespace:editor:fieldmapper',
                                'label_block' => true,
                                'show_label' => false
            ]
        );
```

Our JS Event Listener

```
//register our buttons event hook
        jQuery(window).on("elementor/frontend/init", function () {
                elementor.channels.editor.on('namespace:editor:fieldmapper', function () {
                    console.log("CLICK - open dialog");
                    

/**
*
*
 This is where I cant figure out how to open an elementor modal and populate it with our form.
*/

                });
            });
```